# select lower and upper from lower only table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

How can I transform a normalized table with family, name and 'lowerbound' number to a result set with family, name,  lower and upper bound, where upper bound is defined as `min(lowerbound of family) > current lowerbound` and if no number like this exists, use a provided number

for example, if this is the schema and data:

```
create table records(
  family varchar(10),
  name varchar(10),
  lowbound int(4)
  );

insert into records
values 
('letters', 'a',1),('letters', 'b',3),('letters', 'c',3),('letters', 'd',3),
('letters', 'e',7),('letters', 'f',7),('numbers', '12',1), ('numbers', '15',1), ('numbers', '18',4);
```

and the provided number is 9, then the result set should be:

```
|  FAMILY | NAME | LOWER | UPPER |
|---------|------|-------|-------|
| letters |    a |     1 |     3 |
| letters |    b |     3 |     7 |
| letters |    c |     3 |     7 |
| letters |    d |     3 |     7 |
| letters |    e |     7 |     9 |
| letters |    f |     7 |     9 |
| numbers |   12 |     1 |     4 |
| numbers |   15 |     1 |     4 |
| numbers |   18 |     4 |     9 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
SELECT r1.family, r1.name, r1.lowbound lower, coalesce(min(r2.lowbound), 9) upper
FROM records r1
LEFT JOIN records r2 ON r1.family = r2.family AND r1.lowbound < r2.lowbound
GROUP BY r1.family, r1.name, r1.lowbound
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d303/1)

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to express this is with a correlated subquery in the `select` clause:

```
select r.*,
       coalesce((select r2.lowbound
                 from records r2
                 where r2.family = r.family and
                       r2.lowbound > r.lowbound
                 order by r2.lowbound
                 limit 1
                ), 9) as highbound
from records r;
```

The `coalesce()` handles the case where there is no value.  In that case, your substitution value of `9` is used.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8381/8) is the SQL Fiddle.